# This slide range , when drag to end of right , i want to display text eg: unlimited, How can i do that?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This slide range , when drag to end of right , i want to display text eg: `unlimited`, How can i do that ?

When drag to end of right , normal code will show `$0 - $500` but i want to show `$0 - unlimited`

How can i do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/5Kvk5/1/

```
$(function() {
    var minPriceInRupees = 0;
    var maxPriceInRupees = 500;
    var currentMinValue = 33;
    var currentMaxValue = 333;

    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: minPriceInRupees,
        max: maxPriceInRupees,
        values: [ currentMinValue, currentMaxValue ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            currentMinValue = ui.values[ 0 ];
            currentMaxValue = ui.values[ 1 ];
        }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
" - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5Kvk5/6/

Comment: yes , all right thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking to see if the current max slide value (`ui.values[ 1 ]`) is the same as the `maxPriceInRupees` value like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Kvk5/9/

```
$(function() {
    var minPriceInRupees = 0;
    var maxPriceInRupees = 500;
    var currentMinValue = 33;
    var currentMaxValue = 333;

    $( "#slider-range" )
    .slider({
        range: true,
        min: minPriceInRupees,
        max: maxPriceInRupees,
        values: [ currentMinValue, currentMaxValue ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {

            $( "#amount" )
                .val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + (ui.values[ 1 ] == maxPriceInRupees ? 'Unlimited' : ('$'+ui.values[ 1 ])) );

            currentMinValue = ui.values[ 0 ];
            currentMaxValue = ui.values[ 1 ];

        }
    });   

    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " - " + ($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) == maxPriceInRupees ? 'Unlimited' : ('$' + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ))));
});
```

Comment: thank you , and how to change `class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header"` in ie7 to `8px` ?

Comment: This links explains how to target IE7 specifically. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters--net-10575 although I would use a conditional comment instead with a seperate IE stylesheet as this link describes http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html